# Worker process is not being called in simple example?

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, python-multiprocessing

Here's my simple example code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import multiprocessing
import time

def some_function():
    return "hello!"

def get_address_type(address):
    return 'tcp'

class PseudoThing():
    def __init__(self, address):
        self.address = address
        self.server = None

    def attach(self):
        if get_address_type(self.address) == 'tcp':
            ip, port = self.address.split(':', 1)
            self.server = some_function()
        else:
            self.server = some_function()

    def worker(self):
        print("in worker!")
        for i in range(10):
            print("I'm a worker doing worker things...")
            self.attach()
            if self.server:
                return True
            time.sleep(0.2)

    def parent(self):
        print("I'm a parent doing parent things!")

    def start_process(self):
        p = multiprocessing.Process(target=self.worker)
        print("starting process")
        p.start()
        return p

def main():
    nvr = PseudoThing("kitty")

    p = nvr.start_process()
    p.join()


print("__name__ = {}".format(__name__))
if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("doing main!")
    main()
```

However, nothing is getting printed out from worker, as I would expect. Instead, this is the output of the program:

```
__name__ = __main__
doing main!
starting process
```

I am suspecting this has something to do with the class structure (I recall having issues with this on Python 2), but I am not entirely sure. Where can I add more print statements to figure what's going on? Where *are* things going wrong?

Comment: What version of python and what OS are you running on? I tested this on both Ubuntu 16.04 / Python 3.5.2 and Windows 10 / Python 3.4.3, both appeared to work as intended up until a ValueError on line 19 in attach (since 'kitty' doesn't have a colon to split on there aren't enough values to unpack)

Comment: @MostlyHarmless I am using Windows 10, Python 3.6 (using Anaconda).